# Bookmarking LMS, Moodle SCORM

Tags: javascript, moodle, scorm

Hi im looking a way to bookmark a page with JavaScript so that when a user reopens a course it remembers the page he or she is on by sending it to SCORM/Moodle.

any ideas folks?

using scorm 1.2 and Moodle 1.9:)

Many Thanks

```
<!-- ================ -->
<!-- Bookmarking start -->
<!-- ================ -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="SCORM_API_wrapper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Using pipwerks namespace, SCORM 1.2

var success = pipwerks.SCORM.init();

if(success){
  var status = pipwerks.SCORM.get("cmi.core.lesson_status");
  if(status != "completed"){
    success = pipwerks.SCORM.get("cmi.core.lesson_status", "completed");
    if(success){
       pipwerks.SCORM.quit();
    }
  }
}

function setbookMark() {
    var setlessonLocation = scorm.set("cmi.core.lesson_location", "2");
}

function showbookMark() {
    alert(scorm.get("cmi.core.lesson_location"));
}

window.onload = function (){
    init();
    setbookMark();
}


</script>
<!-- ================ -->
<!-- Bookmarking End -->
<!-- ================ -->
```

First index page that is loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SCORM_API_wrapper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var scorm = pipwerks.SCORM;


function init(){

    //Specify SCORM 1.2:
    scorm.version = "1.2";

    var callSucceeded = scorm.init();
}

function end(){

    var callSucceeded = scorm.quit();
}


function bookMark() {
    var lessonLocation = scorm.get("cmi.core.lesson_location");
    if (lessonLocation == "1") {
        window.location = "1.html";
        }
    else if(lessonLocation == "2") {
        window.location = "2.html";
        }
    else if(lessonLocation == "3") {
        window.location = "3.html";
        }
    else if(lessonLocation == "4") {
        window.location = "4.html";
        }
    else if(lessonLocation == "5") {
        window.location = "5.html";
        }
    else if(lessonLocation == "6") {
        window.location = "6.html";
        }
    else if(lessonLocation == "") {
        window.location = "1.html";
        }
}

window.onload = function (){
    init();
    bookMark();
}

window.onunload = function (){
    end();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this (theoretically) need to be done from the Moodle side? I.e. write a plugin/component that keeps track of the last page the user was on and bring it back up when the user logs back in.

Comment: Should be able to add JavaScript to each page that send a bookmark to SCORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `lesson_location` is the equivalent of creating a browser cookie... you need to write JavaScript in your course that parses the saved string and makes use of it.

You need to change your code in a number of places -- the code you've provided is an example that sets your course to complete the instant it's initialized. It isn't really what you're looking for.

Here's a quick primer on starting the course and looking for a bookmark:

```
var bookmark, initialized, status;
var scorm = pipwerks.SCORM; //shortcut for easier typing

function jumpToPage(url){

    //write some code that navigates to the specified url

    //Save whatever URL was just used as the bookmark
    //each time the function is invoked.
    scorm.set("cmi.core.lesson_location", url);

}

function init(){

    //the default URL in case no bookmark is found
    //or when course is launched for first time
    var url = "url_of_first_page.html";

    initialized = scorm.init();

    if(!initialized){ alert("Course failed to initialize"); return false; }

    //Get the lesson status from the LMS
    status = scorm.get("cmi.core.lesson_status");

    if(status === "completed"){

        //You're already done, get out of here
        scorm.quit();
        return; //exit init() function

    } else if(status === "ab-initio"){

        //this is the very first launch, no bookmark will be found in LMS
        //do nothing

    } else {

        //Check for a bookmark
        bookmark = scorm.get("cmi.core.lesson_location");

        //If a bookmark is found, use its value as the target URL
        if(bookmark){ 
            url = bookmark;
        }

    }        

    jumpToPage(url);

}


window.onload = init;
```

Comment: So i would still need to include the above page as well?

Comment: No, it isn't very well formed. You need an HTML page to act as the parent page -- it should contain all course navigation and tracking logic. Then you display course content inside an iframe. To navigate between pages, you set the src of the iframe, you *don't* use window.location. I suggest starting with a functional example from a respected source like scorm.com, they have plenty of free examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cmi.core.lesson_location to store the learners current location in the course. If you need to store more complex information like the learners current state in the course then use cmi.suspend_data. These are both read/write properties that you can read when the course first loads and connects to the LMS and then navigate to the appropriate location within the course.

Quick reference on the CMI properties can be found under the Data Model section: http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/

Comment: Thanks so far i have the above but im still stuck :S any ideas?

Comment: Setting lesson_location does not make the course player automatically navigate to that location the next time the course is loaded. It is just a container for the value. Your course still has to get that value when it first loads and determine if it needs to act on it by navigating to a specific location.